# How to make the compare in jquery with json code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

if buy one each price is $100, if buy >= 2 each price is $90.  if buy >=5 each price is $80. if buy >=8 each price is 70.........

**the json data is dynamic**, namely which  elements is 1 or 2 or 3 or another: so you don't know what the value of the price_qty will be.

```
[{"price_id":"1","website_id":"0","price_qty":2,"price":"90.0000"},
 {"price_id":"2","website_id":"0","price_qty":5,"price":"80.0000"},
 {"price_id":"3","website_id":"0","price_qty":8,"price":"70.0000"}]
```

supporsed there is a variable named result, which has the quantity of the product that the visitor will buy.

`var result`.

now, i want to do: compare the result with the json data (price_qty), then output the whole price.
eg: `if(result >2) { write the qty is +result, the price is + price.}`. how to write the code?

once i used :

```
var myObject= the json data,
jQuery.each(myObject, function(_index, _item){ 
var objectInArray = _item; 
if(objectInArray.price_qty  result)

...
```

then i don't know how to do the left.

Comment: i tried to use each function to get i want, but then don't know how to write the condition

Comment: You want to find the item which has a price_qty equal to the result?

Comment: not equal, want to compare with the result, then count the whole price

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if the qty is 7, you want to use priceqty 5? which is 7*80? or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

```
// first sort the array
var sorted = arrayWithJsonData.sort(function(a,b){return a.price_qty - b.price_qty;});

// find the nearest price qty
var i=0;
while(i < sorted.length && sorted[i].price_qty <= result){i++;} 

var price = sorted[i-1].price;
```

Comment: +1, this is what he needs. This will find the closest pricing record where the price quantity is less than or equal to the result quantity.

Comment: @Barak,i using the code:var object=jQuery("#object").text();
// first sort the array
var sorted = object.sort(function(a,b){return a.price_qty - b.price_qty;});

Comment: first in php i did: echo '<div style="display:none;" id="object">'.$object.'</div>'; then using in jquery, it shows TypeError: object.sort is not a function

Comment: jQuery("#object").text() returns a string
if you get the json data from string you should use $.parseJSON() to convert it to an array.
var object= $.parseJSON(jQuery("#object").text());
keep in mind, object here is actually an array